# Recursive sort of regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm trying to build a regular expression where I been asked to filter string like:

`country:India provinces:Uttranchal city:Dehradun zip_code:12345`

from the string like this:

`keyword: one two three country:India provinces:Uttranchal city:Dehradun zip_code:12345 filter: myparameter`

Now I have prepared a basic regex like:

```
country:\w+|provinces:\w+|city:\w+|zip_code:\w+
```

Which sort of does the work for me If `country`,`provinces`,`city` are single words

But if they are not 
example

`keyword: one two three country:United-States provinces:Manhattan city:New-York zip_code:12345 filter: myparameter`

The above reqex just not work because of the limitation of non word character like `-`

You can assume that the country,province or city and have word that join by many `-`

like

`country:United-States-of-America provinces:Washington-Dc city:New-York-West`

**etc
etc ...**

so `-\w+` is kind of recursive pattern with 0 or more occurence in either `country`,`provinces`,`city` or all of them

Now I also tried build a regex for the same something like this

`(country:\w+(-\w+)*)|(province:\w+(-\w+)*)|(city:\w+(-\w+)*)|(zip_code:\w+(-\w+)*)`

This although matches
but as you can see in rubular [screenshot](http://i49.tinypic.com/2qjxhcj.png)  attach that it also presented non accepted output and nil

all I want is to avoid the `non-accepted` and `nil` output which causes problem in match result when segregating the desired string from the given input string or can somebody suggest me better regex than this.

Comment: Regular expressions don't work in a way that will help you directly. If you are working in a programming language that supports regular expressions, then there are some really easy solutions to what you want to do. However, what language are you working in? Ruby? If you let us know we can provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: @AndrewMartinez Yes Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a group of one or more letters and dashes, you can just use brackets to indicate a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `[\w\-]+`

```
country:[\w\-]+|provinces:[\w\-]+|city:[\w\-]+|zip_code:[\w\-]+
```

Two-line example in Python:

```
>>> s = "keyword: one two three country:United-States provinces:Manhattan city:New-York zip_code:12345 filter: myparameter"
>>> print re.findall("country:[\w\-]+|provinces:[\w\-]+|city:[\w\-]+|zip_code:[\w\-]+", s)
['country:United-States', 'provinces:Manhattan', 'city:New-York', 'zip_code:12345']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(...)` are capture groups. Ruby (if that's what you're using) also supports non-capture groups `(?:...)`, so I think you want:

```
(country:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(province:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(city:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(zip_code:\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

or even:

```
(country:\w+(?:-\w+)*|province:\w+(?:-\w+)*|city:\w+(?:-\w+)*|zip_code:\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

if you want them all in capture group 1.